Google Play Store Showing 'Update' Instead of 'Install' After App Uninstallation
I've developed a Flutter app and deployed it to the Google Play Store. However, I've encountered an issue where, after users uninstall the app, attempting to reinstall it from the Play Store shows an "Update" button instead of "Install." This occurs despite the app being previously uninstalled from the device. Selecting "Update" results in no action since the app is no longer on the device.
How can I ensure that when users uninstall my app, they can reinstall it appropriately from the Google Play Store?
I utilized the adb uninstall --appName command to remove the app from my device, which effectively resolved the issue of the Play Store showing "Update" instead of "Install." However, it's important to note that this solution is only applicable to developers or users with access to Android Studio terminal.
Unfortunately, regular users do not have access to the Android Studio terminal or the ability to run adb commands. Therefore, while this solution worked for me as a developer, it is not a practical resolution for the general user base.

I assume Google manages your signing keys? Was the old app version also installed via Google or directly from APK? May be the users managed to uninstall the app but keep the data. If then the APK signature has changed it would make sense for Play Store to show "update" but installation will fail as the signatures do no longer match.
